# Select the first and last record based on the condition

Tags: r, data.table

I am having a dataset like below.

```
ID    Use   Group
13A Sheet1  Out
13A Sheet2  In
13A Sheet3  Out
13A Sheet4  In
13A Sheet5  Out
```

For selecting the first and last record by ID, I can do like below based on the @akarun answer.

```
df = df[ , Index := 1:.N, by = "ID"]
```

However, how to add a condition within that in data.table. Eg: I want to select the first records with "IN" value in group field.

Comment: Do you care which value of group the last record is?

Comment: No, only the first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this ?

```
library(data.table)
df[, .SD[c(which.max(Group == "In"), .N)], by = ID]

#    ID    Use Group
#1: 13A Sheet2    In
#2: 13A Sheet5   Out
```

Or in base R using `ave`

```
subset(df, ave(Group == 'In', ID, FUN = function(x) 
           seq_along(x) %in% c(which.max(x), length(x))))
```

Comment: But I need the last record of a group as well. But for last value group is not a constraint. Just the last record

Comment: @ssan Updated the answer to include last row of the group.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Actually, this gives me the first "IN" Entry record. Also if there is no first "IN" record, this gives me the first "OUT" records and the last record. For mu current scenario, this is what actually I need. However, for learning just curious that how it gives the first record if there is no "IN"

Comment: @ssan because we are using `which.max` here. `which.max` returns the index of highest value in the vector. Here as we are comparing  `Group` with `"In"`, we get a logical vector. When we use `which.max` on it , if there is any `TRUE` value it will return index of first `TRUE` (since `TRUE > FALSE`) if there is no `TRUE` value it will return the index of first `FALSE` value because now `FALSE` is h highest in the vector. Compare output of `which.max(c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))` and `which.max(c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and it is really useful. Now I get the use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Note that this will create duplicates if the last record is the first one with group == 'In' or there is only one record for an ID:

```
library('tidyverse')

first_ins = df %>% 
  filter(Group == 'In') %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()

output = df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  bind_rows(first_ins) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Group)
```